How can I withdraw funds from a smart contract ? And how can I know if my contract has the function to withdraw the funds or not?
Can you please check my contract too ? I don't know how to check if there is a feature to withdraw the fund or not.
My contract is: 0x0c88833f3f7980A29283a1c3202793d353f7F49A

The address posted above does not represent a contract's address
https://etherscan.io/address/0x0c88833f3f7980A29283a1c3202793d353f7F49A
this seems to be a wallet. you can transfer balances from this wallet, if you have access to the corresponding mnemonic phrase.
For comparison: This is a contract's address
https://etherscan.io/address/0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d
Note the word "contract" below the Etherscan logo in the top left corner

Thank you for your answer. It was my mistake. This is my contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0x0bf3005DF2ce0BFa2BAc05729D33Af75FD6CE621 Can you please check it for me if I can withdraw the balance from it ?

you need to verify the contract on etherscan.io so that i can see the solidity code. if you do not verify, etherscan only shows the bytecode which is not readable by humans. Alternatively, you can copy/paste the code here.
